# PHP Scoped Output Buffer, How?

Tags: php, output-buffering

> How to stack output buffer so that each buffer will have their own ID?

So, I have a HTML page with buffers, but also have a page content that connected with [a hook](https://github.com/mecha-cms/extend.plugin.block-e). The hook itself also contains output buffer:

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <?php ob_start(); ?>
    <?php echo $page->content; ?>
    <?php echo ob_get_clean(); ?>
  </body>
</html>
<?php ob_get_clean(); ?>
```

The first `ob_get_clean()` just stopped the output buffer from the HTML page.

So, is it possible to have a mechanism like this?

```
<?php ob_start('#template'); ?>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <?php ob_start('#page'); ?>
    <?php echo $page->content; ?>
    <?php echo ob_get_clean('#page'); ?>
  </body>
</html>
<?php ob_get_clean('#template'); ?>
```

So that each `ob_get_clean()` will have their own value:

- `#template` → `<html> … </html>`
- `#page` → `<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>`

I got these errors:

```
[28-May-2017 09:17:01 Asia/Jakarta] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot destroy active lambda function in G:\server\www\lot\extend\plugin\lot\worker\block-e\index.php on line 5

[28-May-2017 09:17:01 Asia/Jakarta] PHP Stack trace:

[28-May-2017 09:17:01 Asia/Jakarta] PHP   1. {main}() G:\server\www\index.php:0

[28-May-2017 09:17:01 Asia/Jakarta] PHP   2. require() G:\server\www\index.php:48

[28-May-2017 09:17:01 Asia/Jakarta] PHP   3. Hook::fire() G:\server\www\engine\fire.php:117

[28-May-2017 09:17:01 Asia/Jakarta] PHP   4. call_user_func_array:{G:\server\www\engine\kernel\hook.php:79}() G:\server\www\engine\kernel\hook.php:79

[28-May-2017 09:17:01 Asia/Jakarta] PHP   5. do_fire() G:\server\www\engine\kernel\hook.php:79

[28-May-2017 09:17:01 Asia/Jakarta] PHP   6. Route::fire() G:\server\www\engine\fire.php:113

[28-May-2017 09:17:01 Asia/Jakarta] PHP   7. call_user_func_array:{G:\server\www\engine\kernel\route.php:140}() G:\server\www\engine\kernel\route.php:140

[28-May-2017 09:17:01 Asia/Jakarta] PHP   8. {closure:G:\server\www\lot\extend\page\index.php:46-168}() G:\server\www\engine\kernel\route.php:140

[28-May-2017 09:17:01 Asia/Jakarta] PHP   9. Shield::attach() G:\server\www\lot\extend\page\index.php:166

[28-May-2017 09:17:01 Asia/Jakarta] PHP  10. ob_end_flush() G:\server\www\engine\kernel\shield.php:90

[28-May-2017 09:17:01 Asia/Jakarta] PHP  11. Shield::{closure:G:\server\www\engine\kernel\shield.php:84-88}() G:\server\www\engine\kernel\shield.php:90

[28-May-2017 09:17:01 Asia/Jakarta] PHP  12. Hook::NS() G:\server\www\engine\kernel\shield.php:86

[28-May-2017 09:17:01 Asia/Jakarta] PHP  13. call_user_func_array:{G:\server\www\engine\kernel\hook.php:94}() G:\server\www\engine\kernel\hook.php:94

[28-May-2017 09:17:01 Asia/Jakarta] PHP  14. Hook::fire() G:\server\www\engine\kernel\hook.php:94

[28-May-2017 09:17:01 Asia/Jakarta] PHP  15. call_user_func_array:{G:\server\www\engine\kernel\hook.php:79}() G:\server\www\engine\kernel\hook.php:79

[28-May-2017 09:17:01 Asia/Jakarta] PHP  16. fn_twitter_cards_replace() G:\server\www\engine\kernel\hook.php:79

[28-May-2017 09:17:01 Asia/Jakarta] PHP  17. Page->__get() G:\server\www\engine\kernel\hook.php:8

[28-May-2017 09:17:01 Asia/Jakarta] PHP  18. Hook::NS() G:\server\www\engine\kernel\page.php:79

[28-May-2017 09:17:01 Asia/Jakarta] PHP  19. call_user_func_array:{G:\server\www\engine\kernel\hook.php:94}() G:\server\www\engine\kernel\hook.php:94

[28-May-2017 09:17:01 Asia/Jakarta] PHP  20. Hook::fire() G:\server\www\engine\kernel\hook.php:94

[28-May-2017 09:17:01 Asia/Jakarta] PHP  21. call_user_func_array:{G:\server\www\engine\kernel\hook.php:79}() G:\server\www\engine\kernel\hook.php:79

[28-May-2017 09:17:01 Asia/Jakarta] PHP  22. fn_image_set() G:\server\www\engine\kernel\hook.php:79

[28-May-2017 09:17:01 Asia/Jakarta] PHP  23. Page->get() G:\server\www\lot\extend\plugin\lot\worker\image\index__.php:7

[28-May-2017 09:17:01 Asia/Jakarta] PHP  24. Page->content() G:\server\www\engine\kernel\page.php:170

[28-May-2017 09:17:01 Asia/Jakarta] PHP  25. Page->__call() G:\server\www\engine\kernel\page.php:170

[28-May-2017 09:17:01 Asia/Jakarta] PHP  26. Page->__get() G:\server\www\engine\kernel\page.php:42

[28-May-2017 09:17:01 Asia/Jakarta] PHP  27. Hook::NS() G:\server\www\engine\kernel\page.php:79

[28-May-2017 09:17:01 Asia/Jakarta] PHP  28. call_user_func_array:{G:\server\www\engine\kernel\hook.php:94}() G:\server\www\engine\kernel\hook.php:94

[28-May-2017 09:17:01 Asia/Jakarta] PHP  29. Hook::fire() G:\server\www\engine\kernel\hook.php:94

[28-May-2017 09:17:01 Asia/Jakarta] PHP  30. call_user_func_array:{G:\server\www\engine\kernel\hook.php:79}() G:\server\www\engine\kernel\hook.php:79

[28-May-2017 09:17:01 Asia/Jakarta] PHP  31. fn_block_replace_e() G:\server\www\engine\kernel\hook.php:79

[28-May-2017 09:17:01 Asia/Jakarta] PHP  32. Block::replace() G:\server\www\lot\extend\plugin\lot\worker\block-e\index.php:9

[28-May-2017 09:17:01 Asia/Jakarta] PHP  33. preg_replace_callback() G:\server\www\lot\extend\block\engine\kernel\block.php:73

[28-May-2017 09:17:01 Asia/Jakarta] PHP  34. Block::{closure:G:\server\www\lot\extend\block\engine\kernel\block.php:69-73}() G:\server\www\lot\extend\block\engine\kernel\block.php:73

[28-May-2017 09:17:01 Asia/Jakarta] PHP  35. call_user_func_array:{G:\server\www\lot\extend\block\engine\kernel\block.php:72}() G:\server\www\lot\extend\block\engine\kernel\block.php:72

[28-May-2017 09:17:01 Asia/Jakarta] PHP  36. {closure:G:\server\www\lot\extend\plugin\lot\worker\block-e\index.php:4-9}() G:\server\www\lot\extend\block\engine\kernel\block.php:72

[28-May-2017 09:17:01 Asia/Jakarta] PHP  37. ob_start() G:\server\www\lot\extend\plugin\lot\worker\block-e\index.php:5
```

Thank you.

Comment: I will try to play around with this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-level.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the value of **ob_get_clean** to a variable

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <?php ob_start(); ?>
    <?php echo '$page->content'; ?>
    <?php $inner = ob_get_clean(); ?>
  </body>
</html>
<?php $outer = ob_get_clean(); ?>
<?php var_dump($inner, $outer); ?>
```

*Please note that I put quotes around **$page->content** to make it easy to read this code, you should not use those quotes.*

Comment: Yes, I did put the output content on a variable every time the output buffers end. And that’s why I use output buffer. But I don’t know why with that error messages.